# Removing useless lines in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, linter

I use Vs code for my coding.However I am getting weird lines in my code. Happens only when I am editing a .c file and not with .py file. Does anyone know a quick fix for this? Thanks.
[image: pics related]

[image: pics related]

Comment: Those lines are to show you where each coding block is.

Comment: @ewong how do i remove them?

Comment: search settings for `bracket`, VSC now includes a rewrite of `Bracket Pair Colorizer`